# Routing and testing a nested form for associated models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, nested-forms

I'm creating a Rails app for an animal shelter that allows you to input an animal and its breed(s) for display on the website. To account for breed mixes, I have a many-to-many association set up on my two models, Pet and Breed. But I want to be able to create the pet and create/find/assign the breed from the same form. I've stumbled into nested form territory, and hard coded the breed part of the form with html, but for the most part it seems to be doing what I want it to, until I test with Capybara and throw all sorts of fun errors. I've seen all of these (and a few more), but I'm a bit new to Rails and not exactly sure what they're telling me: 
`ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template pets/add_breed, application/add_breed`

`ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: pet`

`Failure/Error: visit '/pets/new/add_breed' NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

I'm thinking what I have is maybe a sloppy solution, and I must be missing some routes or something, and was hoping someone could explain to me exactly where my form(s) are sending data (and how to write a test that will pass).

form partial rendered on view:

```
 <%= form_for(@pet) do |f| %>
    <% if @pet.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@pet.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this pet from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
         <% @pet.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
         <% end %>
        </ul>
       </div>
    <% end %>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
...
  <form action="/pets/new/add_breed" method= "post">
     <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch">
  <div class= "field">
    <label for="breed_name">Breed</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="breed[breed_name]" id="breed_name"/>
  </div>
  <div class ="actions">
    <input type ="submit" name="commit" value="Save Pet"/>
  </div>
</form>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  match('pets/new/add_breed', {:via => :post, :to => "pets#add_breed"})
  match('pets/new/add_breed', {:via => :patch, :to => "pets#add_breed"})
  match('pets/new/add_breed', {:via => :get, :to => "pets#create"})
  match('pets/new/add_breed', {:via => :get, :to => "pets#update"})

  match('pets', {:via => :patch, :to => "pets#create"})

  resources :breeds
  resources :pets
end
```

My add_breed method lives on the Pets Controller but is only called within the create and update methods. Here are those:

pets_controller.rb

```
  def update
    add_breed
    @pet.breeds << @breeds
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pet.update(pet_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pet, notice: 'Pet was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @pet }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @pet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @pet = Pet.new(pet_params)
    add_breed
    @pet.breeds << @breeds
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pet.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pet, notice: 'Pet was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pet }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @pet.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def add_breed
      @breeds = []
      # Check to see if the breed's name exists yet, and if so, use that breed id
      breed_name_string_from_user = params[:breed][:breed_name]
      @breed = Breed.find_or_create_by(breed_name: breed_name_string_from_user)
      @breeds << @breed
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you've set any POST or PATCH to 'pets/new/add_breed' to call the add_breed action in your PetsController.  From your code though it seems that add_breed really isn't an action, just a helper method in the controller.  If this is the case you should make the add_breed method private in the controller, and your routes are probably supposed to be

```
match('pets/new/add_breed', {:via => :post, :to => "pets#create"})
match('pets/new/add_breed', {:via => :patch, :to => "pets#create"})
```

or more concisely as

```
match('pets/new/add_breed', via: [:post, :patch], to: "pets#create")
```

also note that with your GET routes only the first one will ever match, so it'll never call update (It's also against REST practices to have create or update actions on a GET request, not to mention potentially creating issues with caching of web requests)

Comment: Implementing these routes made everything so much cleaner!! Thank you for your explanation. Still doesn't solve my testing issue, but I managed to get answers from elsewhere--will post what I learned also.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is the form within a form--it's a big no no, apparently, because the result is undefined. Every browser renders a nested form differently. Chrome rendered my page exactly as I wanted it to, totally by chance, because it prioritized the nested form. My testing environment prioritized the outer form, which is why my tests broke.

The field for breeds still works on this form though, all I needed to do was remove the  wrapper.

```
<%= form_for(@pet) do |f| %>
   <% if @pet.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
       <h2><%= pluralize(@pet.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this pet from being saved:</h2>

       <ul>
        <% @pet.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
         <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
       </ul>
      </div>
   <% end %>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
...
  <div class= "field">
    <label for="breed_name">Breed</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="breed[breed_name]" id="breed_name"/>
  </div>
  <div class ="actions">
    <input type ="submit" name="commit" value="Save Pet"/>
  </div>
<% end %>
```